# How can I block Nmap scanning on macOS?

Tags: macos

I would like to stop others from using Nmap to scanning my Mac.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Blocking nmap is like forbidding everyone to check whether your doors and windows at home are locked. Better to make sure that they are actually locked.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You can prevent some Nmap probes (ICMP probes, to be specific) by enabling stealth mode  in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nmap tool is tricky and designed to evade firewalls, so you might need a hardware firewall or assistance from a network administrator based on how skilled the operator of nmap is.

*You can’t be on a network and remain totally invisible.*

That being said, enabling the firewall and configuring it to drop incoming connections is usually good enough.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642

Be sure to go into advanced and choose **Block all incoming connections**

This breaks many functions for sharing out, which is precisely what nmap detects.